# Make RxCocoa binding for UIPageViewController.setViewControllers (how to synchronize Observable)

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

currently, I want to bind the value of `Observable<UIViewController>` to my `UIPageViewController`. Initial idea is simple and straightforward:

```swift
viewControllerObservable
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] viewController in

        self?.pageVC.setViewControllers([viewController], 
                                        direction: .forward, 
                                        animated: false, 
                                        completion: nil)
     })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

but if values in viewControllerObservable changes too quick, page view controller receives new set command before it's done with adding previous view controller and I'm getting `NSInternalInconsistencyException`.

I can make that code more "reactive", using `Binder`, but I'll still face the same problem.

Pretty obvious way here is to use throttle, but it seems to be pretty dirty fix, masking problem, not fixing it.

Ideally, I need some way to hold further values handling until `completion` is called in `setViewControllers`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, best solution I've come so far, is to use second observable for the purpose of sync.

```swift
let sync = BehaviorSubject<Void>(value: ())

Observable.zip(pageProvider.selectedViewControllerObservable, sync)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] viewController, _ in
        self?.pageVC.setViewControllers([viewController],
                                        direction: .forward,
                                        animated: false,
                                        completion: {sync.onNext()})
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

As `Observable.zip` waits for both observables to emit value, it will be "locked" until `sync` will receive next value.